# Python how does the extend method of list for iterator as argument works?

Tags: python-3.x

Suppose I have a list

```
L = [1, 2]
```

and

```
iter_L = iter(L)
L.extend(iter_L)
```

its gives me memory error how this above step works?

Comment: If you iterate through `L` adding each element into `L`, you will never reach the end.

Comment: ohh... Thanks I didnt thought of that.@khelwood